# Android PagerSnapHelper preload next page data before user moves to it (like setOffscreenPageLimit in ViewPager2)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing one app which showing Instagram kind of post feed with a media slider. I had developed a post media slider using Recyclerview with PagerSnapHelper to show a list of media as a horizontal pager list. But it loads only media that is visible to the user not preloading next media. I did googling but didn't find how to setting up off screen limit for pages in this case. I know we can do this with ViewPager2 by using `setOffscreenPageLimit` method but not sure about how to do in my usecase of Recyclerview with PagerSnapHelper. I afraid that i might have to rewrite media slider using ViewPager2.

Comment: _RecyclerView_ already handles pre-fetching of off-screen views out of the box. See [this post](https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710). Is that not working for you or are you anticipating a problem?

Comment: Okay, I went through the shared post and also setting up prefetch count using `setInitialItemPrefetchCount()`. But still not loading image in next page in RecyclerView until I swipe a page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem and ultimately discovered a solution in the source code of `ViewPager2`. It incorporates an internal implementation of `LinearLayoutManager`, overriding the `calculateExtraLayoutSpace()` function. Consequently, I implemented the same `LayoutManager` and applied it to my RecyclerView which used `PagerSnapHelper`:

```
   val layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.context, HORIZONTAL, false) {

        private val offscreenPageLimit = 2 // number of pages that will be retained to either side of the current page

        override fun calculateExtraLayoutSpace(state: RecyclerView.State, extraLayoutSpace: IntArray) {
            val offscreenSpace: Int = getPageSize(this) * offscreenPageLimit
            extraLayoutSpace[0] = offscreenSpace
            extraLayoutSpace[1] = offscreenSpace
        }
    }

    fun getPageSize(layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager): Int = with(recyclerView) {
        if (layoutManager.orientation == LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) {
            width - paddingLeft - paddingRight
        } else {
            height - paddingTop - paddingBottom
        }
    }
```